# How to change color of List Item(textView) in listView permanently?

Tags: android

I want to change the color of TextView(List Item) in ListView permanently?

I want like News, if i open the all items are highlighted when i click on one item the color is changing to some dull look and it sticks permanently.

But when i scroll the ListView the Color changes to other List Items 
In the Below image i just Clicked on "About Durga" again i came back to this screen and i scrolled the ListView then the Other Item are also effecting. even i didn't click.

please send any code fro that.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

```
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),view.getSelectedItem().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            defaultSet.add("no data");

            setOfClickedItems.add(id + "");

         //  parent.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);


            final SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("disablePref", MODE_PRIVATE);
            final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            Set<String> disableList = prefs.getStringSet("disable_option", defaultSet);
            Iterator<String> iterator = disableList.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                setOfClickedItems.add(iterator.next());
            }

            editor.putStringSet("disable_option", setOfClickedItems);
            editor.commit();

            Log.e("putshared",setOfClickedItems.size()+ "set size" + setOfClickedItems);


            Intent newsIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsDescriptionActivity.class);
            newsIntent.putExtra("title", ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.news_heading)).getText().toString());

            newsIntent.putExtra("image_url", newsItems.get(position).getImgUrl());

            newsIntent.putExtra("summary", newsItems.get(position).getSummary());
            newsIntent.putExtra("desc", newsItems.get(position).getDescription());

            startActivity(newsIntent);

        }
    });
```

**My adapter**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    defaultSet.add("default");

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }


    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_news_reader, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_heading);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.news_image);
        holder.buttonView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.forward_button);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    News rowItem = (News) getItem(position);


    String img_url = rowItem.getImgUrl();
    URL newurl = null;
    Bitmap mIcon_val = null;
    try {
        newurl = new URL("http://10.2.195.165:9000" + img_url);

        Log.e("NEW URL", "++++++++++" + newurl);
        mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
        Log.e("BitMap", "++++++++++" + mIcon_val);


    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("disablePref",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    Set<String> disableList = prefs.getStringSet("disable_option",defaultSet);
    Log.e("setsize",disableList+"items"+disableList.size());
    Iterator<String> iterator = disableList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String iteratorValue = iterator.next();
        Log.e("inside iterator",""+iteratorValue+"view position"+position);
        if((position+"").equalsIgnoreCase(iteratorValue)) {
          Log.e("inside if",""+iteratorValue+"matched position"+position);
           // convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);

        }

    }

    holder.txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getTitle());
    holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(mIcon_val);

    holder.buttonView.setTypeface(font);


    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the image?

Comment: Are you using a custom Adapter for your listview? Please show the relevant code

Answer (score 1):

getView() recycles your Views as you scroll. You change the text color of an item to gray in getView, and that View will be recycled. Hence, even text of items that you haven't clicked will also turn gray.

In your getView(), you've only defined what color the text should have if it was clicked. However, you forgot to define what the color should be if the View hasn't been clicked at all.

Change the code in your while-loop to this (also add the boolean wasClicked):

```
  boolean wasClicked = false; //false by default

  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        String iteratorValue = iterator.next();
        Log.e("inside iterator",""+iteratorValue+"view position"+position);
        if((position+"").equalsIgnoreCase(iteratorValue)) {
           wasClicked = true; //item was clicked
        }
   }

   //now let's change the text color based on if the item was clicked or not
   if(wasClicked){ //set color appropriate for clicked items
      holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
   }else{ //item wasn't clicked
      holder.txtTitle.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); //or whatever color you want
   }
```

Comment: Yeah am storing all colored items(clicked items) index in db and am getting the stored list of indexes from db in getView ,and am checking condition that index is equal to current getView position ,even though color is applying to other items while scrolling and i have tried with SaharedPreferences also,but giving same result.Please help me out .

Comment: I've edited my answer. Please accept mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem.

Comment: HI Frank, Thank You Very much. it is worked for me. you saved my time

Answer (score 0):

You basically need to store state of each list item in you adapter(i.e. was it clicked) and then in adapter's `getView(position ...)` you have to adjust the background color for the view.

Your random behavior stems from reusing the views(they maintain the state between different `getView(position ...)`).

Comment: Actually i need to apply color for list item permanently even after close and open app i want to see the selected list items with color So for that am storing clicked list item positions in DB and getting those indexes in getView and comparing with current getView position but color is also applying for other list items as well while scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

you have to follow this step for this

1:- Go to item_news_reader.xml file 
 2:- inthat file you have given textfields and image at same xml file you can set color of text by this line

```
 android:textColor="#000000"
```

or try this programatically

```
 extView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#bdbdbd"));
```